# Using MongoDB Projection

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, mongo-go

I have the following structure in my database:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fc4fc68fcd604bac9f61f71"
  },
  "init": {
    "fullname": "Besikta Anibula",
    "parts": [
      "Besikta",
      "Anibula"
    ],
    "alt": "Besikta Ani."
  },
  "industry": "E-Commerce"
}
```

I´m trying to just access the init object and write the results to a structured variable in Go:

```
var InputData struct {
    Fullname    string  `bson:"fullname" json:"fullname"`
    Parts       []string`bson:"parts" json:"parts"`
    Alt         string  `bson:"alt" json:"alt"`
}

collectionRESULTS.FindOne(ctx, options.FindOne().SetProjection(bson.M{"init": 1})).Decode(&InputData)
js, _ := json.Marshal(InputData)
fmt.Fprint(writer, string(js))
```

But the result is empty:

```
{"fullname":"","parts":null,"alt":""}
```

It is working when not using a projection like:

```
var InputData struct {
    Ident   primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id" json:"id"`
}

collectionRESULTS.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{}).Decode(&InputData)
js, _ := json.Marshal(InputData)
fmt.Fprint(writer, string(js))
```

Result as expected:

```
{"id":"5fc4fc68fcd604bac9f61f71"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the projection to only retrieve the `init` property of the result documents, and then you try to unmarshal into a struct value that does not have any matching field for the `init` value, so nothing will be set in that struct value.

You must use a value that has an `init` field, like this wrapper `Result` struct:

```
type Result struct {
    Init InputData `bson:"init"`
}
type InputData struct {
    Fullname    string   `bson:"fullname" json:"fullname"`
    Parts       []string `bson:"parts" json:"parts"`
    Alt         string   `bson:"alt" json:"alt"`
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var result Result
err := collectionRESULTS.FindOne(ctx, bson.M{}, options.FindOne().
    SetProjection(bson.M{"init": 1})).Decode(&result)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```